# How to evaluate $\int \frac{1+\cos 2x}{\sin^2 2x}$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals, fractions

I'm trying to calculate  $\int \frac{1+\cos2x}{\sin^2 2x}$ for the third time and I'm still getting the same result. As usual I tried substitution:

$u = 2x$

$$\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{1+\cos u}{\sin^2 u} = \frac{1}{2} *\int \csc^2 u + \int \frac{\cot u}{\sin u}$$

$$\frac{1}{2} *[-\cot u + \int \cos u ]$$

$$\frac{-\cot 2x}{2} + \frac{\sin 2x}{2}$$

The solution in my textbook is completly different, however. What's wrong with my method?

Comment: How did you get from $\int \frac {\cot u}{\sin u} \ du$ in one line to $\int  \cos u \ du$ in the next.  You should have $\int \csc u \cot u \ du$ instead

Comment: @Doug Exactly same, i dont know what he did there

Comment: @DougM Indeed, I messed up with the arithmetic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again here is the problem $\int \frac{\cot (u)}{ \sin (u) } du= \int \csc( u)  \cot( u) du = -\csc (u)$.

So final solution according to your method is :

$$-\frac{1}{2}\left(\cot(2x) + \csc(2x)\right) + c$$

Answer (score 3):

$${\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{\cos\left(2x\right)+1}{\sin^2\left(2x\right)}\,\mathrm{d}x  ={\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{\csc^2\left(x\right)}{2}\,\mathrm{d}x  =\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-1}{\dfrac{1}{2}}}{\displaystyle\int}\csc^2\left(x\right)\,\mathrm{d}x =-\dfrac{\cot\left(x\right)}{2} + C$$

Comment: Forgive my ignorance but what did you do with cos 2x?

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{1+\cos2x}{\sin^22x}=\frac{2\cos^2x}{4\sin^2x\cos^2x}=\frac{1}{2\sin^2x}$$
and we got $\cot$.